# Acquiring the ping of a certain user.[Discord.Net]

Tags: events, gateway, args

I cannot find the ping for a certain user in usereventargs no matter how I look for it. Is there a way to get it from somewhere?

For clarification: I made a bot that has to react in a certain way to the ping of a certain user that I have identified (for example he used a command and I know his name).